# Сохраниться ли ссылка при переносе приложения в другой аккаунт разработчика Google Play?

Tags: google-play

Доброго времени суток!

Изучал документацию гугл по данному вопросу но не нашел ответа на интересующую меня тему, а именно, если переносится приложение от одного паблишера к другому, то сама ссылка сохраниться или изменится?

Также интересует, допустимо ли нативное приложение заменить на реакт натив приложение, если сделать обновление релиза в сторе?

Comment: о какой ссылке речь?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhiliaoapp.musically
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.disneyplus
Привел примеры ссылок.
Id останется или изменится?

Comment: айди вшито в приложение и к разработчику не относится. Чего бы ему меняться. Если изменить айди, то это технически будет другое приложение.

Comment: Т.е. сразу второй вопрос добавлю, если я вместо первого приложения в тот же аккаунт сделаю замену на другой apk файл другого приложения, например было нативное приложение, начали другую разработку и сделали другое кросс приложение, ID изменится?

Визуально приложение для пользователя тоже самое, но архитектура меняется.

Comment: что вам оказалось непонятно из моего комментария? :) если я вместо книги в твердой обложке положу в сумку книгу с мягкой обложкой, название книги в сумке изменится?

Comment: Тогда это будет другая книга и id изменится. Как можно сохранить id в таком случае?

Comment: я спрашивал про название, а не про id. Если я вместо Евгения Онегина в твердой обложке положу Евгения Онегина в мягкой обложке, то название не изменится. Потому что название с типом обложки не связано. Так же как не связано айди приложения с разработчиком. Если вы не измените айди, то оно не изменится. А если измените, то это будет другое приложение. Вам известно, что это за айди и откуда оно берется?

Comment: Вы прояснили мне многие моменты, я нашел ресурс где указано как можно повлиять на ID https://victormochere.com/ru/how-to-change-android-application-id

Comment: я думаю, что там немного не о том. Если у вас приложение ``com.disney.disneyplus``, то после изменения например на ``com.disney.disneyplusplus`` это для системы будет другое приложение, даже если вы там больше ничего не измените. И пользователи не получат это обновление. Зачем вам вообще менять айди? Оно ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Цель, при замене на другое приложение - сохранить прежний ID который был.

Comment: каждый раз, когда вы обновляете приложение, технически вы устанавливаете другое приложение. Именно айди определяет приложение, а не то, что в этом приложении. Вы можете под одним и тем же айди сегодня опубликовать фотокамеру, завтра браузер, послезавтра еще-что нибудь.